# How do I make an excel sort work with variables?

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I am trying to do a sort using this code:

```
Range(BRPdest).Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batch Record Progress").sort.SortFields.clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batch Record Progress").sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
Range("D12"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batch Record Progress").sort
    .SetRange Range(ActiveCell.Column & ":12", ActiveCell.Column & ":125")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

i recorded a macro and got this but it had static ranges

I need it to find the relevant column which the first line should do,

it should sort the column from cell 12 to 125(or less), the data in the cells is formatted "A12345"

when the code gets to the .apply line it throws error 1004, i think there might be something wrong with my Key: (I have also tried putting the key to the same as the range with the same error)

Can somone point out what i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: BRPdest = "$P$27" incase that is relevant

Comment: You cannot sort column `P` with column `D` as criteria. The criteria range must be within the sorted range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to a combination from wedge and A.S.H

I have solved it

```
    Range(BRPdest).Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batch Record Progress").sort.SortFields.clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batch Record Progress").sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range(Cells(12, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(125, ActiveCell.Column)), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batch Record Progress").sort
        .SetRange Range(Cells(12, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(125, ActiveCell.Column))
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

I had to change the range to the format wedge suggested and use that in the key aswell

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The .Column property returns the numerical index of a column, not the alphabetical letter you use in a Range reference. You can use (sheet).Cells(row,column) to refer to a single cell range using a numerical row and column reference.

```
Range(BRPdest).Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batch Record Progress").sort.SortFields.clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batch Record Progress").sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
Range("D12"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Batch Record Progress").sort
    .SetRange Range(Cells(12,ActiveCell.Column), Cells(125,ActiveCell.Column))
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

If the size of data you are sorting can vary, you will probably want to find what the last row in your data set, instead of relying on a fixed row number.

Comment: I made the changes (with an extra ')' after the range) but I still get the same error